# Can the client modify react component state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an admin page for an application and have a state value 'authenticated' that flips from 'false' to 'true' after a successful login (which is authenticated on the server) which then shows the actual admin panel.

Are component state values safe from tampering by the client? Basically, if the client can modify my 'authenticated' state value to 'true', they can skip the login and go straight to the admin panel (which I obviously don't want).

I read that React Dev Tools allows the client to modify values yet everyone says "validate on the server" but I am validating on the server and updating my state accordingly, if the user is approved. If it is not wise to have a state value manage this, what is the right way to conditionally show the admin page after a successful, server-side authenticated login?

I think this is an important question since tampering with state values in a React app can have huge negative consequences on data integrity within an app/database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Either require an authentication token with every request or require authentication through a session.

---

Never trust users always. One potentially big issue is if you "hide" admin actions behind the admins page without requiring authentication.

For example, assume the backend server uses a REST API to accept commands. In the admin panel you get links to administrative actions like a button 'Delete Everything' that sends a DELETE request to `server.net:8080/api/admin/everything` without requiring any authentication. If you're a user, you can find that in the code potentially and then send a DELETE request to that address from anywhere without any repercussions *(assuming you don't have the API restricted to the website via CORS)*.

> We'd never give administrative privileges to anyone who would want to delete everything... Because we'll never untrust someone. Right?

Worse, someone might find the server and fuzz some inputs to it, and oops! They manage to delete everything (or even worse, GET everything stored in the database). This wouldn't be hard to do, especially if the server you use to authenticate is the same server you use to issue commands. History has proven "security through obscurity" to be a very bad paradigm. Every action should be authenticated, even if it seems like the actions will be hard to find.

Generally, providing [a JSON web token](https://jwt.io/) or some other form of authentication token and having the user send that with every request is a good start at least, especially if it has an expiration date. The token would be provided through a separate request with valid credentials.

Sending a token with every single request obviously isn't ideal. There are a couple of other things to try. For servers using PHP, you can probably trust sessions (though very many people who know more than me would probably disagree). In more modern cases, you could try to use [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), requiring the token after connection. Then only after authentication with the token do you allow the user to make administrative requests.

That way, even if a user knows the exact command they can send to perform any action, the server won't let them without a current session or token. Unfortunately, unless you're already using Web Sockets or depending on a session, it will likely require a lot of changes. I'd consider this to be critical though.

Comment: Ok, I think I was getting hung up on someone somehow getting into my admin panel through changing the component's state but I guess they won't be able to do anything as long as I ensure they're verified on each call to my server script.  I'm using Node so I'll either do websockets or keep a token in localStorage.

Comment: Indeed - even if they manage to get to the admin page somehow, if the information you return for that page depends on their authentication token then they gain no information and can't do anything malicious. You can use some sort of authentication on the client side and check if they have permissions, of course. It's important to keep in mind in that case that the checks are for the user experience, not for the security of your application as a whole. WebSockets are really cool, I highly recommend them!

Answer (score 5):

It is always possible to tamper values in the front-end, there is no way you can rely solely on the front end to ensure security.

Your best approach is to implement some form of authentication and authorization on your backend. In this way, even is some users pretend to be admin, they will be blocked when you do the next request to the server.

Perhaps if you can send more information regarding your problem, we can think of a more specific solution.

Comment: I chose the other answer because it was more thorough and gave specifics on how to handle authentication in a React app. Appreciate your response.

Comment: sure! thank you for the feedback!! I hope you manage to go further in your project! :)